# PHP insert into database

Tags: php, javascript

I have a web form which saves a part number in 3 split text boxes. I would like to save this part number into the database as the id number of the part number.Is there any way on how the number can be joined and then compared to the id value and used in the insert statement?I read somewhere that you can use implode function to do that.Well i did use implode to store the date but so far regarding this problem, its not been helpful.

```
    <td onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'id_nr_1\').focus();">
 St&uuml;cklistennummer'.$pflicht_id_nr.'
    </td>
    <td align="left" onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'id_nr_1\').focus();">
    <input type="text" class="'.$html_klasse_id_nr_1.'" id="id_nr_1"   name="id_nr_1" size="2" maxlength="4" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["id_nr_1"]).'" onfocus="this.focus();" onkeyup="FocusWeiter(this.id, \'id_nr_2\');">
    <input type="text" class="'.$html_klasse_id_nr_2.'" id="id_nr_2" name="id_nr_2" size="1" maxlength="3" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["id_nr_2"]).'" onfocus="this.focus();" onkeyup="FocusWeiter(this.id, \'id_nr_3\');">
                                <input type="text" class="'.$html_klasse_id_nr_3.'" id="id_nr_3" name="id_nr_3" size="1" maxlength="3" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST["id_nr_3"]).'" onfocus="this.focus();" onkeyup="FocusWeiter(this.id, \'id_nr_4\');">

    </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this on the PHP side, simply concatenate the numbers. Assuming they are submitted via three textboxes from a form on the client side name id1-3:

```
$id=$_REQUEST["id1"].$_REQUEST["id2"].$_REQUEST["id3"];
//Further processing?
$query="INSERT INTO `tablename` (`id`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES ('$id', '$value2', '$value3')";
//Query the database
```

If this is too non-specific for you, it's because I don't have actual code to work with, nor knowledge of your database setup.